# CSS Sprite Doesn't Work Because Width/Height defines container

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

So, on my website RedRoll.com I'm trying to implement CSS sprites.
(If you scroll down you will see a scrolling container under "Exclusive!")

```css
.simply-scroll-btn-left {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000 url('https://www.redroll.com/wp-content/themes/steam/images/arrow-left.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 7px 12px !important;
}
```

As you can see, there is a black background behind the current arrow. The background is 34px x 100%.

But here's the problem. The width and height defined in the CSS creates the black container around it, so if I try to specify the width/height of the icon in my sprite, it also changes the size of the container.

How do I keep the black background size the same but specify the size of the icon? Also, how do I center the sprite in the middle of the black background like it is currently?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well? In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**.

Comment: can you update any  Example like `https://jsfiddle.net`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and your constraints, this problem may be solvable using pseudo elements.

One approach might be to slightly modify the styles for the existing CSS as below, and add a floating icon via a pseudo element.

This should give you the control you need to size, and select unique icons from your icon sprint/atlas:

[UPDATED] Sorry, just noticed my original answer was missing: `content:''` in the pseudo selector - please ensure this is added

```
/* Leave existing styling for box sizing mostly untouched, with minor adjustments */
.simply-scroll-btn-down {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #000; // Remove image, etc
    position:relative; // Add this so that pseudo element can be centered
}

/* Display a pseudo element for icon */
.simply-scroll-btn-down:after {

    //[UPDATE] This is required
    content:'';

    position:absolute;
    display:block;

    // This translates the pseduo element for centering
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    // This adjusts the pseduo element for centering based on pseduo elements dimensions
    margin-left:-20px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    // Adjust these rules to suit the icon coordinates in your sprite/atlas 
    background-image: url('YOUR_SPRITE_URL');  // Customise as needed
    background-repeat:  no-repeat; // Customise as needed
    background-position: 10px 10px; // Customise as needed
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working unless I'm doing it wrong :(
So to clarify, the width/height of the :after defines the size of the icon in the sprite, then the background-position says the starting coordinates of the icon in the sprite?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed my answer was incomplete - I forgot to include `content:''`, I've updated the answer above. Hope this helps

Comment: Glad I could help :-) feel free to PM me if there's anything else you need help with - have a great day!